# CSS3 background not printing

Tags: jquery, css, printing, charts

I'm trying to use the CSS3 and jquery to create an animated chart.  Here is the site I got the idea from...[The Link](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/23/create-an-animated-bar-graph-with-html-css-and-jquery/)

What i'm struggling with is if someone wants to print the page, the bar charts don't show the bars.  The bars are created using CSS backgrounds... which aren't printing.  Is there something i can do so that they will print for everyone hitting the page... i don't want to have to go into any printer options in the browser, i just want it to print when someone asks it to.
thanks
shannon

Comment: If you want the to print don't put them as backgrounds.  Browsers are all configured to not print backgrounds by default to save ink.

Comment: ok.. i'm just learning CSS... can you tell me what the CSS alternative is to using backgrounds?

Comment: You could potentially render the chart with an image, instead of a background.

Answer (score 1):

printing backgrounds images or css3 way can not be controlled by you but by the user's preferences in the browser.

I only know about a hack around it but how you adapt it to your issue is another thing. So for example you have a image, like the logo of your web site, that won't get printed in the normal way, but if you put it in an ul li (unordered list) or define the display as list-item:

```
display: list-item;
list-style-image: url(pathToImagesFolder/logo.png);
```

This will get printed.
Note: the CSS hack is not guaranteed as Cross-Browser.